# How do I use Android’s “Surface” classes?

Tags: android, surfaceview, glsurfaceview, textureview, surfaceflinger

Is there a detailed explanation of Surface, SurfaceHolder, EGLSurface, SurfaceView, GLSurfaceView, SurfaceTexture, and TextureView?  In particular:

- What’s the difference between SurfaceView and TextureView?
- Do I need to use GLSurfaceView to use OpenGL ES?
- How do Surface and EGLSurface interact?
- What does SurfaceTexture do?
- Why does the stuff I draw on a SurfaceView have to go above or below everything else?
- What is SurfaceFlinger?
- How does composition of the status and navigation bars work?
- While we’re at it, what’s the right way to structure a game loop on Android?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answers to these and many other questions can now be found on the Android Open Source Project web site:

[Android System-Level Graphics](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html)

The document begins with an explanation of the low-level infrastructure, and then explains how the higher-level features are built from them.  The goal is not to provide direct answers to common questions, but rather to describe the system at a level of detail that makes the answers apparent without being overwhelming.

The choice of material and level of detail were heavy influenced by Q&A on stackoverflow.

(Technically this is a link-only answer, but writing 10,000 words here seemed like a bad idea.)

Comment: I like how the question and the response are written on the same minute.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was instituted. But I was more surprised about the 0 minute delay.

Comment: Hello fadden! Thanks for the great writing. May I ask a quick question btw? Is it possible to take a screenshot of a SurfaceView? I've been searching for this but so far it seems I can't.. I don't expect you to explain how to do it here but I just want to know if there is really any way like calling `draw()` on normal Views.