# Difference between TextureView, SurfaceView, Texture and Surface

Tags: android, android-camera2

I was looking at the Camera2 API of Android. In the code at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java#L210, they use the classes `SurfaceView`, `TextureView`, `Texture` and `Surface` without explaining too much.
The documentation is also not a great help when it comes to distinguishing those 4 classes.

Therefore, my question(s): What is a `SurfaceView`, `TextureView`, `Texture` and `Texture` ? What distinguishes them ? What separates them ? What is used for what ?

Every non-document-like explanation would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23414776/294248

Answer (score 7):

`Surface` is a generic object that can have image buffers drawn into it, which is accepted by a number of Android APIs as a destination for output.

The camera2 API is one of them, but EGL, MediaCodec, etc, can all use them as well.
Concrete endpoints that can accept image buffers can usually be converted to a `Surface` one way or another. These include things like some Android `View`s, Media classes like `MediaRecorder` for video encoding, the `ImageReader` class for efficient CPU access to the underlying graphics buffers, etc.

`SurfaceView` is an Android View that represents a hardware overlay surface; it's the most efficient way to draw image buffers to screen.  Because it represents a low-level display primitive, it's a bit clunky to use; you can get a Surface for it from its SurfaceHolder child object's lifecycle callback.

`TextureView` is an Android View that draws image buffers via the GPU.  It's more flexible than SurfaceView, but requires GPU composition to operate so it adds a bit of latency and power overhead.  It can provide a SurfaceTexture to draw into.

`SurfaceTexture` is a representation of a GPU texture that can be drawn into.  You can use it in EGL to render from via its texture ID, and you can create a Surface from it via one of the Surface constructors to give to other APIs to draw into.  TextureView uses it since it's a GPU-based View.

Comment: I like your answer for it's technical notes, but in practice, what does choosing a TextureView or SurfaceView actually mean? I'm not sure which I should choose. Best performance on any Android device is my specific use-case ie a widely used consumer application.

Comment: Today, I'd recommend looking at AndroidX's CameraViewfinder: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/viewfinder/CameraViewfinder - it handles a lot of the annoying aspect ratio sizing, and automatically selects either a TextureView or SurfaceView depending on OS version.